# Error al tratar de generar un pdf con DataGridView C# usando iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, visual-studio-2017, itextsharp

tengo un problema con el codigo que estoy escribiendo para generar un pdf con los datos de un DataGridView.
despues de que cargo el DGV con la consulta de MySQL, y le doy a l boton de generar, lanza un error  que dice: 
"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"
la verdad me estoy guiando de un video en youtube.(Soy nuevo en programacion :3)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

public void exportarPDF(DataGridView DGAusentismo, string nombreArchivo)
    {
        try
        {
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(DGAusentismo.Columns.Count);
            pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
            pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
            pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;
            iTextSharp.text.Font texto = new Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

            //Header
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn columnas in DGAusentismo.Columns)
            {
                PdfPCell celda = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(columnas.HeaderText, texto));
                celda.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
                pdfTable.AddCell(celda);
            }

            //Agregar DataRow 
            foreach (DataGridViewRow Filas in DGAusentismo.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell Celdas in Filas.Cells)
                {
                    pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(Celdas.Value.ToString(),texto));  // El mensaje de error me dice que es esta linea
                }
            }
            var savedialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            savedialog.FileName = nombreArchivo;
            savedialog.DefaultExt = ".pdf";

            if (savedialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(savedialog.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    Document pdf = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, stream);
                    pdf.Open();
                    pdf.Add(pdfTable);
                    pdf.Close();
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A ocurrido un error durante la exportacion: " + error.ToString());
        }
    }
```

El video del cual me estoy guiando es este: [Export Datagridview to PDF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhsGGLREqu8)

Ahora si alguien tiene una mejor guia para exportar los datagridview a pdf le agradeceria de corazon me lo hiciera saber ya que el video esta en ingles y no le entiendo muchas cosas de las que explica.

Gracias

Answer (score -1):

Para exportar a PDF con este método es necesario agregar la referencia.

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Se genera un libro Excel, en el cual se agrega el `DataGridView` y posteriormente se exporta a PDF.

```
private void exportaPDF(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dgvConsulta)
    {
        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "PDF (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                string temp;
                int iColumnas = 0;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlsApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();//creo una aplicación Excel
                xlsApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                Worksheet xlsSheet; //creo una hoja
                Workbook xlsBook; //creo un libro
                xlsApp.Visible = false; //la aplicación no es visible
                xlsBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Add(true);//añado el libro a la aplicación
                xlsSheet = (Worksheet)xlsBook.ActiveSheet; //activo la hoja, para el libro
                //titulo
                xlsSheet.Cells[2, 6] = "Fecha y hora";
                xlsSheet.Cells[2, 7] = DateTime.Now;
                xlsSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "Resultados de la busqueda:";
                for (int iCol = 0; iCol < dgvConsulta.Columns.Count; iCol++)
                {
                    if (dgvConsulta.Columns[iCol].Visible == true)
                    {
                        xlsSheet.Cells[4, iCol + 2] = dgvConsulta.Columns[iCol].HeaderText;
                        iColumnas++;
                    }
                }

                for (int iRow = 0; iRow < dgvConsulta.Rows.Count; iRow++)
                {
                    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < dgvConsulta.Columns.Count; iCol++)
                    {
                        if (dgvConsulta.Columns[iCol].Visible == true)
                        {
                            temp = dgvConsulta[iCol, iRow].Value.ToString();
                            xlsSheet.Cells[iRow + 5, iCol + 2] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //formato          
                xlsSheet.Columns.Font.Name = "Arial";
                xlsSheet.Columns.Font.Size = 12;
                xlsSheet.Columns.AutoFit(); //Ajusta ancho de todas las columnas
                xlsSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, fichero.FileName,
                                             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard,
                                             true, true, 1, 10, false);
                //xlsApp.Visible = true;
                xlsApp.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error durante la generacion del reporte: \n" + e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); }
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("El reporte ha sido guardado con exito\n¿Desea visualizar el reporte recien creado?",
                        "Guardado de Reportes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            { Process.Start(fichero.FileName); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No necesariamente necesitas eso para generar un pdf.

Comment: Lo sé, es uno de muchos métodos, no tengo conocimientos sobre `iTextSharp`, pero este método es bastante efectivo, inclusive, con algunas pequeñas modificaciones permite exportar a EXCEL